# Execute command usage fails

Tags: robotframework, scp, dropbear

```
*** Settings ***

    Documentation      Transfer a file from OCU to PC
    Library            SSHLibrary
    Suite Setup        Open Connection and Login With Public Key
    Suite Teardown     Close All Connections

*** Variables ***

    ${REMOTE HOST}    192.168.x.xxx
    ${USER}           xxx

*** Keywords ***

    Open Connection and Login With Public Key

    Open Connection     ${REMOTE HOST} 
    Login With Public Key     ${USER}     /home/bhushan/.ssh/id_rsa

*** Test Cases ***


    Run the given command on the console

    ${pwd}= Execute Command     pwd

    Should Be Equal     ${pwd}      /home/root 

    ${output}=  Execute Command     ls

    ${output}=  Execute Command        scp /home/root/myfile.txt bhushan@192.168.x.xxx:/home/bhushan/vdr-reports/
    Log ${output}
```

I have Dropbear of the latest version installed on my target. I am trying to run the above SSH Library Robot framework keyword based test case which defines to transfer a file from remote to the local host. The execute command keyword works in the beginning i.e. ${output}=   Execute Command     ls, but i am getting an error while using the same keyword in copying the files, i.e i can't see anything happening on the console. It is hanging and i waited for long time to see the output but haven't seen anything. But this works when i copy the files to my local machine manually. Can anyone here try to help me in fixing this error.

> KEYWORD ${output} = SSHLibrary . Execute Command scp
>   /home/root/myfile.txt bhushan@192.168.x.xxx:/home/bhushan/vdr-reports/
>   Documentation:     Executes `command` on the remote machine and returns
>   its outputs. Start / End / Elapsed:   20170829 10:26:23.897 / 20170829
>   10:26:50.148 / 00:00:26.251 10:26:23.898  INFO    Executing command 'scp
>   /home/root/myfile.txt
>   bhushan@192.168.x.xxx:/home/bhushan/vdr-reports/'...................>

This is what i see in the log

Comment: I would suggest to use `robotframework-scplibrary` for copying files. I also had problem in the past using only `SSH Library` but this piece of python package solved my problem.

Comment: Why are you not using the [Get file](http://robotframework.org/SSHLibrary/latest/SSHLibrary.html#Get%20File) keyword to retrieve the file?

Comment: Hi Bryan. I already tried with GetFile keyword. The same thing happened i.e. its not working and causing error

Comment: What is the error when you call `Get File`?

Comment: SSHException:EOF during negotiation